# How do I prove the following differential equation is homogenous of degree 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, homogeneous-equation

I understand that if I have a differential equation that I can write in the form of

$$
A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0
$$

, where $A(x,y)$ and $B(x,y)$ are both homogenous functions of the same degree, then I proved the equation is homogenous of that degree.

I can easily prove that functions are homogenous of degree 0.

However, in the following equation I could not make if of the form $A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0$ for some reason.

The equation in question is:

$$
dy/dx=e^{y/x}+y/x
$$

I tried moving $dy/dx$ over to the right side of the equation, however I ended up with $e^{y/x}*dx/dy+y/x*dx/dy=0$.

How do I put in the form of $A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy=0$?

Comment: Don't expand.  Just "multiply by $dx$" on both sides and move dy over.

Comment: @user10354138 then I'd get $(e^{y/x}+y/x)*dx/dy=0$ no? What do I do then? It's multiplying by both members

Comment: Multiplying both sides of $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{y/x}+\frac{y}x$ by $dx$ gives $dy=(e^{y/x}+\frac{y}x)dx$.  Moving $dy$ over, you get the required form with $A(x,y)=e^{y/x}+\frac{y}x$, $B(x,y)=-1$.

Comment: @user10354138 How do you prove the function A(x,y) is homogenous of degree 0 then?

Comment: $\exp(\frac{\lambda y}{\lambda x})=\exp(\frac{y}x)$ etc.